# cannot access any websites on server

Tags: centos, domain

I am having a nightmare with my VPS at the moment, it is running Centos 5.10 final and plesk 11.

I get no response whatsoever when I try to access a domain on the server - by no response I mean nothing is written to the error or access log and I just get a blank screen with a spinning icon in the tab title bar (chrome), I can see from the output of the top command that qmail-queue is hammering the CPU but even when I disable the qmail service and restart the httpd service I get no response from domain names. I have also tried disabling the mysqld service to see whether an issue connecting to databases was causing the issue, but the domain still hangs when that is disabled too.

Here is an example of the logs being written to /var/log/messages:

```
Jun 24 12:04:44 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.146#54040: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:46 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.146#41365: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:46 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.16.83#48813: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:46 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.146#43042: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:46 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.16#37336: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:47 server109-228-19-53 xinetd[2629]: EXIT: smtp status=0 pid=12910 duration=7(sec)
Jun 24 12:04:47 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.17#54200: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:47 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.17#47752: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:48 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.20#46098: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:48 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.17#60778: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:48 server109-228-19-53 xinetd[2629]: START: smtp pid=12995 from=::ffff:151.246.123.181
Jun 24 12:04:48 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.16.82#33203: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:49 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.148#62951: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/AAAA/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:49 server109-228-19-53 xinetd[2629]: EXIT: smtp status=0 pid=12995 duration=1(sec)
Jun 24 12:04:49 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.16.80#52686: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/A/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:49 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.41.144#58112: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/A/IN' denied
Jun 24 12:04:50 server109-228-19-53 named[3256]: client 74.125.16.84#54709: query (cache) 'www.ultragardens.co.uk/A/IN' denied
```

Here is my `top` output, after stopping the qmail service:

```
31753 root      15   0 27612 2420 1676 S  2.0  0.1   0:02.09 sshd
3521 root      25   0  461m  90m  10m S  0.3  4.5   0:30.38 httpd
1 root      15   0 10372  704  596 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.66 init
2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.07 migration/0
3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/1
6 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1
7 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1
8 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/0
9 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/1
10 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 khelper
27 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthread
32 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/0
33 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/1
34 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid
89 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/0
90 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/1
93 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
95 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kseriod
173 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
174 root      19   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 pdflush
175 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.12 pdflush
176 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kswapd0
177 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/0
178 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/1
318 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
353 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/0
354 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/1
355 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_aux
362 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vmbusQ/0
363 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vmbusQ/1
364 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/0
365 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/1
366 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/0
367 root      17  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/1
368 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/0
369 root      17  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/1
370 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/0
371 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/1
372 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/0
373 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/1
374 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/0
375 root      17  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/1
376 root      16  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/0
377 root      17  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 control/1
398 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
433 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kstriped
446 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksnapd
461 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.85 kjournald
486 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kauditd
519 root      14  -4 12720  812  412 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.22 udevd
1203 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpathd/0
1204 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpathd/1
```

This is the server disk space usage:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       135G   95G   34G  75% /
/dev/hda1             251M   54M  185M  23% /boot
tmpfs                1005M     0 1005M   0% /dev/shm
```

I can ping the domain name that I try to access and it replies with the correct ip address, and I have full access to plesk, so apache in general must be working correctly(?). Can anyone please recommend any steps I can take to diagnose the issue?

I have also tried restarting the Named service,  to see if that resolved any DNS issues, but apparently not.

I appreciate I am not a server administrator, but to disregard my issue on that basis I think is alittle harsh - but if there's anything that may be useful that I have omitted please let me know, thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: check disk or memory usage

Comment: disk has 34GB available - why the downvote?

Comment: Helping without detailed information (configs, error messages,...) is like reading the glass sphere. Please provide more info.

Comment: `I have full access to plesk, so apache in general must be working correctly` -- No. Plesk is a different process.

Answer (score 2):

Diagnosing websites in general:

- Can you telnet to your host on port 80? Send `GET / HTTP/1.0` followed by two carriage returns. Do you get any output? (This is a basic webserver comms test).

If you get connection refused: The port is closed, usually means webserver isn't running.

If you get connection timed out, it means for whatever reason, the port is unreachable. This usually means problems with network topology or a firewall. If you can ping it, but not get this response... topology isn't the problem, and it's a firewall getting in the way.

If that's all fine, then it's something else - try connecting on port 80 and expanding on your 'GET' requests - e.g. `GET http://yourhostname/target_url HTTP/1.0` - see if that gives the output you expect.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, apache is running ok as I have full access to plesk and service httpd status confirms it is running, I have also tried service iptables stop with the aim of identifying whether the firewall was the issue with my accessing domains on the server, and that is not the issue either

Comment: Although when I tail /var/log/messages I see many entries along the lines of: query (cache) 'domainname/ANY/IN' denied - is this symptomatic of the issues I am having do you know?

Comment: Googling your approximate error messages suggests it's DNS related. Can you connect to your web server on port 80? Can you connect to your domain names on port 80? If DNS resolution is broken, then that could well explain why you're having this problem, as your client will be waiting for a timeout.